# limit number of listbox items to be displayed on load, programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, sharepoint-2007, silverlight-2.0

I have a Silverlight 2.0 listbox which reads in data from a custom list @ SharePoint 2007. How may i limit the number of items to be displayed on load of Page.xaml?

Here i have @ Page.xaml.cs:

```
private void ProcessResponse()
        {
            XDocument results = XDocument.Parse(_responseString);

            _StaffNews = (from item in results.Descendants(XName.Get("row", "#RowsetSchema"))

                        //where !item.Element("NewsThumbnail").Attribute("src").Value.EndsWith(".gif")
                        select new StaffNews()
                        {                   
                            Title = item.Attribute("ows_Title").Value,
                            NewsBody = item.Attribute("ows_NewsBody").Value,
                            NewsThumbnail = FormatImageUrl(item.Attribute("ows_NewsThumbnail").Value),
                            DatePublished = item.Attribute("ows_Date_Published").Value,
                            PublishedBy = item.Attribute("ows_PublishedBy").Value,
                        }).ToList();
            this.DataContext = _StaffNews;
            //NewsList.SelectedIndex = -1;            
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put `.Take(20)` behind `ToList()` to take only 20 items from the list.

Comment: Thankx for the response :> Im getting the error: Cannot implicitly convert type ‘System.Collections.Generic.Inumerable <News.StaffNews>’ to System.Collections.Generic.List<News.StaffNews>’. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) when i do a .ToList().Take(3); Please show me the light?

Comment: Thanks alot anyw. Somehow i've came across another approach that worksaround the error i encountered. Simply, i did a:


ToList().GetRange(0,3);

Comment: @Mike, don't use this approach, it will fetch your entire database and then only read the first 4 rows. Just use Take(4).Tolist()

Comment: Appreciate it, your method works as well! :> if possible, do you mind taking a look at another small problem that requires your expertise as well? Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799117/enable-button-on-another-xaml-page

Answer (score 1):

[Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) method allows you to set a limit on the items. It will only iterate the collection until the max count is reached. You can just use it instead of `ToList()` or in case of `_StaffNews` is defined as `List<T>`, just combine them `.Take(items).ToList();`

```
private void ProcessResponse()
{    
            var items = 10;
            XDocument results = XDocument.Parse(_responseString);

            _StaffNews = (from item in results.Descendants(XName.Get("row", "#RowsetSchema"))

                    //where !item.Element("NewsThumbnail").Attribute("src").Value.EndsWith(".gif")
                    select new StaffNews()
                    {                   
                        Title = item.Attribute("ows_Title").Value,
                        NewsBody = item.Attribute("ows_NewsBody").Value,
                        NewsThumbnail = FormatImageUrl(item.Attribute("ows_NewsThumbnail").Value),
                        DatePublished = item.Attribute("ows_Date_Published").Value,
                        PublishedBy = item.Attribute("ows_PublishedBy").Value,
                    }).Take(items);
            this.DataContext = _StaffNews;
            //NewsList.SelectedIndex = -1;            
}
```

Comment: Hey,appreciate your help! Again, i learnt quite a bit from you guys :)